# How to access IServiceCollection and/or IServiceProvider outside of Startup class?

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-4.0, .net-core

I am using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection in .Net Farmework 4.6.2 class libraries. How to access IServiceCollection and/or IServiceProvider from outside the source code where they are instantiated, Main(), for instance? I could create a static class exposing this property in a separate class library and referenced it but I am wondering if there is any other better way of achieving this objective. .Net Framework has ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance. Is there any similar thing in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection? Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: ServiceLocator is an *anti* pattern. You *don't* need it when using dependency injection. The *DI container* creates instances from the root down. The instances should *never* even know about IServiceProvider. If you check any ASP.NET Core project you'll see that the classes don't need it at all

Comment: Then how do you resolve the interface / get the instance in other parts of the application which need it?

Comment: Just like any other DI container. In this case, ServiceProvider is the DI container. You ask for the root instance of the service/object you want and *ServiceProvider* will go and find what dependencies there are, instantiate them and pass them to the root object, all the way down.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no singleton "Instance". You can create as many different service providers as you like. You can pass it as a parameter normally.

You can *inject* the `IServiceProvider` into any class that gets instantiated by it. Simply add it as a constructor parameter.

Comment: That's an *anti* pattern. The IServiceProvider is the one that *creates* instances. If you pass *it* as a dependency you are breaking the pattern

Comment: Then how do you resolve the interface / get the instance in other parts of the application which need it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So how do you handle the need to create more instances of a class (or interface) that cannot be determined at creation time of the object? Lets say you have a ClassRoom that will check the database and will need to create Desk objects? Pass it a DeskObjectFactory? What else is an IServiceProvider?

Comment: @nvoigt the same way .NET Core ans ASP.NET Core does? By doing *nothing*, and letting the container initialize constructor dependencies?

Comment: @KokHowTeh You can pass it the same as any other instance in your program. You need to be more specific if you have a situation where you have problems with it. Do you get errors?

Comment: @nvoigt you'll notice that ASP.NET Core projects *don't* need a reference to IServiceProvider in the controllers. They expose the dependencies as constructor parameters. Your ClassRoom is a DbContext-derived class, which *is* typically injected in the constructor

Comment: @nvoigt `IServiceProvider` doesn't mean you don't need factories either, especially when you need named instances, like those provided by [Autofaq](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html)

Comment: @nvoigt constructor injection is one way. Another way is to use IServiceProvider.GetService / GetRequiredService. So the problem arises in this second way as to how other parts of the application has access to the IServiceProvider instance created at the application Main()

Comment: @KokHowTeh no it's not another way. [Service Locator is a well-known *antipattern*](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) that forces you to take a direct dependency on the DI container itself. You can easiliy use IServiceProvider in a console application just fine. Chek the June 2016 article of MSDN Magazine on [Dependency Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt707534.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that uses a console application as an example.

Comment: @KokHowTeh that's not theoretical. I have many console ETL tools, even in .NET 4.7.1 that use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection and *never* pass the `IServiceProvider` interface to any classes. They aren't trivial either. They download ticket files from airlines and banks, parse them and insert them to databases. I have one `services.GetRequiredService<Whatever>()` in my `Main()` that retrieves a fully configured instance of the root class I want, pass a few parameters and run it.

Comment: @KokHowTeh All that's needed is to configure the service provider and Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration at the start. Even database connections, API keys are injected through the Configuration service.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, let's talk ASP.NET... how do you think Scopes are working? By some instance having a `IServiceProvider`, calling `CreateScope` and passing *that* scope further down the line. I don't see how passing an `IServiceProvider` would break the pattern, as long as that service provider is used to create instances of stuff. I also don't see how creating countless empty "Factories" that just wrap the `IServiceProvider` is a good pattern, assuming we talk C# and not the overzealous pattern obsession of Java.

Comment: I don't say you *should* do it, because normally you should not *need* it, but if you have to (because it's not known at constructor time which other services you need) you can.

Comment: I am aware of it and have read the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt707534.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 However, it is not practical to modify so many constructors of the application as that will involve too many code changes to so many class libraries for a trivial purpose of getting access to the IServiceProvided.

Comment: @KokHowTeh then get ready for your colleague's curses in the future. I still ask forgiveness for creating a `ServiceLocator` four years ago.

Comment: @KokHowTeh You should not *need* the `IServiceProvider` in all those classes. Maybe you should ask a more specific question for your use-case?

Comment: @KokHowTeh I agree, you don't need and shouldn't use IServiceProvider in this case. You can't even test a class in this case without configuring the entire thing. *Without* the service locator you can just mock a dependency's interface in a test. *With* it, you have to configure everything just to make a single call. They didn't like it, especially after the 10th time they had to write DI config code for a test file

Comment: It's the other way round. I am cursing my previous colleagues as the app is not designed for DI.  It was using the legacy ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance all over the place to resolve instances because it doesn't use constructor injection.

Comment: Well in that case I'm afraid the "correct" way to use DI is to actually write the classes in a way that supports it (i.e. constructor injection).

Comment: I was looking for the similar solution with  ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance as a shortcut to use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection to replace UnitContainer.

Comment: Constructor injection does not work for a singleton class accessed through Instance with default constructor...

Comment: @KokHowTeh While true, I cannot help people with "Singleton" problems. Don't use singletons. That's the solution. In 20 years of professional programming, I have not seen a single use case where it had been used for it's intended purpose. I have seen plenty of people who think global variables are good as long as they wrap them in a pattern. They are not. It's still global variables and still crap for all the reasons that are well known. "Singleton" is an anti-pattern. (Not to be confused with Singleton lifetime in DI containers, that's neither a pattern nor bad).

Comment: @nvoigt There is one more problem. WCF per-call needs a parameterless constructor for ServiceHost and constructor injection does not work in this case. Any idea?

Comment: @KokHowTeh Did you try to google "WCF dependency injection"? You need a custom ServiceHostFactory. Some DI containers have nuget packages that already bring some, for others you neeed to do that yourself.

Answer (score 15):

Different from the `IServiceProvider`, the `IServiceCollection` can't be injected into a class constructor.

As many have already said, you should avoid using them directly. But **if you really need** to  do so for the `IServiceCollection`, you can create a "Provider", such as:

```
    public interface IServiceCollectionProvider 
    {
        IServiceCollection ServiceCollection { get; }
    }

    public sealed class ServiceCollectionProvider: IServiceCollectionProvider
    {
        public ServiceCollectionProvider(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            ServiceCollection = serviceCollection;
        }

        public IServiceCollection ServiceCollection { get; }
    }
```

Registering:

```
services.AddSingleton<IServiceCollectionProvider>(new ServiceCollectionProvider(services));
```

Using:

```
    public class YourController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;
        private readonly IServiceCollection _services;

        public YourController (IServiceProvider provider, IServiceCollectionProvider serviceCollectionProvider)
        {
            _provider = provider;
            _services = serviceCollectionProvider.ServiceCollection;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time, `IServiceProvider` *should not be used* directly, because it will result in the [Service Locator antipattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) instead of the Dependency Injection pattern.

However, there are cases where it does make sense. Especially in multithreaded WPF or Blazor applications, where you need multiple scopes for the database access. To to so, you simply inject the `IServiceProvider` into the constuctor of a class that gets created from it:

```cs
public sealed class ServiceProviderResolver
{
    public ServiceProviderResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; }
}
```

Than you can create new scoped services as needed:

```cs
public static IDisposable Scoped<T>(this IServiceProvider scopeFactory, out T context)
{
    var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    context = services.GetRequiredService<T>();
    return scope;
}
```

#### Example: WPF UserControl

Assuming we are using:

- [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/)
- [Splat.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Splat.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/)
- [ReactiveUI.Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReactiveUI.Fody/)

```cs
public partial class MyWPFControl : UserControl, IViewFor<MyWPFControlViewModel>
{
    private IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; }

    public MyWPFControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Use dependency resolver to get the service provider
        ServiceProvider = Splat.Locator.Current
            .GetService<ServiceProviderResolver>()
            .ServiceProvider;

        this.WhenActivated(d => {
            ActivateCustomerIdSelected(d);
            // ...
        });
    }

    private void ActivateCustomerIdSelected(d)
    {
        this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.CustomerId)
            .Where(id => id != null)
            .Select(_ => this)
            .SelectMany(async (vm, ct) => {
                // Make a database query in a dedicated scope
                // This way we can isolate the context 
                // Such that other threads won't interfer with the context
                using(var scope = ServiceProvider.Scoped<IMyDbContext>(out var context))
                {
                    return await context.Customers
                        .Where(c => c.Id == vm.CustomerId)
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(ct)
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            })
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            // execute the DB query on the TaskPool
            .SubscribeOn(RxApp.TaskPoolScheduler) 
            // Handle the result 
            // Note: we are still on the task pool here
            // you might need DynamicData.SourceCache 
            // or DynamicData.SourceList when handling
            // multiple results
            .Subscribe(customer => { /* ... */ })
            .DisposeWith(d);
        }
    }

    // ...

    [Reactive] public Guid? CustomerId { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: you have a mistake in `(this IServiceProvider scopeFactor` . Should be factory there

Comment: You can now inject and use `IServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope()` instead.